# Sending SmS from Asp.net c# Web site without using external sites

Tags: c#, asp.net, sms, gsm

I want to send sms from asp.net c# website , but I don't want to use any external sites as `Twilio`

Comment: wire a mobile phone to your webservice and send the sms.

Comment: @SirRufo Could you please provide more explanation

Answer (score 3):

You need GSM Modem and you can send SMS through that GSM modem.

Comment: Could you please provide more explanation ?

Comment: Buy GSM modem, then communicate to that GSM modem using SerialPort (as far as I know). Send AT command to send SMS. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38705/Send-and-Read-SMS-through-a-GSM-Modem-using-AT-Com

Comment: Is there any other way?and if no, which external site is more effective to use ?

Comment: The choices are external sites or your own hardware. Just choose the easiest one... have fun...

Comment: Ok, thanks for your precious time, but I ask is there any another external site is better than Twilio ?

Comment: Sorry, never use service like that before... I use my own hardware gsm modem

Comment: Well you excluded explicit **any** external sites/services in your question - so there is the only option to run your own gateway to the cellular network

Comment: @SirRufo So, If I use external Site is there any another external site is better than Twilio ?

Comment: @Sara What do you mean by 'better than Twilio'? Are you talking about price?

Comment: @AlexBaban More Flexible than it, because Twilio needs to verify all telephone numbers to send sms to it